Проблема при попытке скачивания с сайта jut.su
Я столкнулся с проблемой: я получаю url видео аниме, и отправляю запрос. Например, url будет https://r270106.kujo-jotaro.com/onepiece/1.1080.b7759fb3992d9b4a.mp4?hash1=59a043014cf4f110601c25fcc1a39ccc&hash2=701b157de3b27cc1da285009bf55d87c. Но при переходе (что уж говорить про запрос) выдает ошибку 403. Как исправить?
Код:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

LINK = "https://jut.su"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": UserAgent().random
}

class Episode:
    def __init__(self, episode_name: str, href: str) -> None:
        self.name = episode_name
        self.href = href
        
        self.season = href.split("/")[2] if "season" in href else "season-1"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {LINK+self.href}"

class JutSu:
    def __init__(self, slug: str):
        self.slug = slug
    
    def get_all_episodes(self, season: str):
        url = f"{LINK}/{self.slug}"
        if season:
            url += f"/{season}"
        
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(response.text, "lxml")
        
        episodes = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "short-btn"})
        
        return [Episode(episode.text, episode.attrs["href"]) for episode in episodes]
    
    def get_link_for_download(self, href: str, res: str):
        response = requests.get(LINK+href, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(response.text, "lxml")
    
        source = soup.find("source", {"res": res})
        source = source if source else soup.find("source")
        
        return source.attrs["src"] if source else None

result = []
jut = JutSu("eighty-six")
for i in jut.get_all_episodes(''):
    result.append(i)



res = requests.get(jut.get_link_for_download(result[-1].href, "480p"), headers=headers)
print(res)
print(res.text)


Видимо задалбали сервер частыми запросами

Вместо использования fake-useragent, подставь свой. (Можно узнать через "Консоль разработчика" в браузере)

Друзья, если кто то столкнулся с такой проблемой, то используйте сессию:

Создаёте сессию
Когда при получении ссылку на аниме, то используйте сессию
Используйте сессию при отправке запроса на url аниме. Например url: https://r270106.kujo-jotaro.com/onepiece/1.1080.b7759fb3992d9b4a.mp4?hash1=59a043014cf4f110601c25fcc1a39ccc&hash2=701b157de3b27cc1da285009bf55d87c


Проверьте Ваше подключение к сети. Возможно Вы используете VPN или Ваше подключение не стабильно. Перезагрузите роутер, ноутбук/ПК и попробуйте ещё раз.
 200 (Запрос на вытягивание прошел успешно)


То есть код который я предоставил работает на вашем устройстве?

Код 403 сообщает то что запрос на сервер поступил, но сервер отказался обрабатывать запрос же

Да - @EldiProgramm
